# Tab welding for NiMH cells

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, nickel

I'm building a NiMH cell pack capable of more than 30 Amps. I've sourced 0.2mm x 10mm nickel strips, and have no issue welding, and know that I need 2 parallel strips to carry the current I'm pulling from it. But what I don't know is the ampacity of the welds themselves. Almighty google hasn't found me an answer either when I search. Anyone have an answer or formula for calculating the ampacity of the welds?

Comment: Is the contact area of the weld equal to or larger than he cross-section area of the strip?

Comment: @brhans the welder tips are 1.5mm diameter, but I'm not 100% sure of the actual weld diameter. I could presume about 0.8mm. My strips are 0.2mm thick.